# Map Reduce Doubts

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am new to MongoDB as well as to Map-Reduce framework. I have some very basic doubts related to `Map-Reduce` in `mongodb`.

- What is the kind of logic that should be written in `map` stage ? Is it only selection of data on which `reduce` will be called later ?
- What happens when `emit` gets called in a `map` function ? What exactly `emit` intended for ?
- In `.group` function, there is a `reduce` parameter needed ? Why is so ? Why `map` is not needed here ?
- Is it possible to debug `mapReduce` logic in `mongodb` shell ? Is it possible to know how many times each step got called, what data it processed and what data was generated ?

E.g.

I am trying to find sum of numbers from 1 to 100 using map-reduce.

Comment: Honestly way too broad without specific examples. You also need to refer to [`.group()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) which is actually a custom wrapper around mapReduce and not the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline operator which belongs to the aggregation framework. Which BTW, you should probably really be using as opposed to mapReduce unless there is a specific case which cannot be solved that way.

Comment: I have not studied aggregation framework till now. I am trying to solve same problem using all alternatives in mongoDB, to have a sound and comparative understanding of each.

Comment: It was a general commentary and as I said, probably your better solution. But your "question" does not really explain what you want and is far too general. I suggest you ask your real question rather than ask for general opinions, which never provides good and helpful answers.

Comment: You are right. I guess I will give some more time to MapReduce and once I get a hold of this, I will answer it myself here.

Comment: Answer what? I've been prompting you to actually ask a real question. If you truly want to "Learn More" then learn how to ask first. StackOverflow regularly gets flooded by useless information, which we have to remove. Please don't add to the pile. Ask a real question or remove it yourself, so we don't have to waste our time doing that last part for you.

Comment: @NeilLunn `group()` uses server-side JavaScript and supports a `reduce()` function, but is *not* a custom mapper around MapReduce. Source ref: [commands/group.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/db/commands/group.cpp#L90).